# sort by category

Tags: categories, sort

I am outputting a list of channel entries. Each entry has 2 category assignments but I need to sort the list alphabetically by one of the categories.

Here is my current code that sorts alphabetically by entry title:

```
{exp:channel:entries
                    channel="properties"
                    orderby="title"
                    sort="asc"
                    dynamic="no"
                    disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"
                }
                <tr>
                    <td>{title}</td>
                    <td>{categories show_group="4"}{category_name}{/categories}</td>
                    <td>{categories show_group="5"}{category_name}{/categories}</td>
                    <td>{property_sqft}</td>
                    <td><a href="{url_title_path='our-properties/detail'}" class="pluslink">View Property</a></td>
                </tr>
                {/exp:channel:entries}
```

So I basically need to sort the entries by {category_name} of category group 5.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think this would be a good time to use [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) add-on. You could wrap your channel entries tags with Stash set_list, which would save the properties as a Stash variable, and then output the list and orderby/sort by the category 5 field. Overall you would end up with more options for ordering and sorting your list. See the Stash docs for [set_list](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#expstashset_list-tag-pair) and [get_list](https://github.com/croxton/Stash#expstashget_list-tag-pair) for info and examples. Basically it would look like:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="my_list"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="properties"
        orderby="title"
        sort="asc"
        dynamic="no"
        disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    }
        {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
        {stash:item_cat_4}{categories show_group="4"}{category_name}{/categories}{/stash:item_cat_4}

        etc....

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{exp:stash:get_list name="my_list" orderby="item_cat_5" sort="asc"}
    <tr>
        <td>{item_title}</td>
        <td>{item_cat_4}</td>

        etc...

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```